# can enable/disable devise lockable module based on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I would like to disable/enable devise lockable module for users based on specific condition. For example enable lockable module only for non-admin users.

There was an method in `Confirmable` module, `confirmation_required?` which can be overwrite if confirmation is required or not.

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Confirmable#confirmation_required%3F-instance_method

`Lockable` module does have similar method?. any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

put this in you User model:

```
def active_for_authentication?
  super && (admin? || !access_locked?)
end

def valid_for_authentication?
  return super unless persisted? && lock_strategy_enabled?(:failed_attempts)

  # Unlock the user if the lock is expired, no matter
  # if the user can login or not (wrong password, etc)
  unlock_access! if lock_expired?

  if super && (admin? || !access_locked?)
    true
  else
    self.failed_attempts ||= 0
    self.failed_attempts += 1
    if attempts_exceeded?
      lock_access! unless access_locked?
    else
      save(validate: false)
    end
    false
  end
end
```

It is from the docs site:
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Lockable#active_for_authentication%3F-instance_method

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it overwrite two devise methods that makes little scary, especially overwriting `valid_for_authentication?` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can put below method in your user.rb file

```
def lock_strategy_enabled?(strategy)
  return false if self.admin?
  true
end
```